# Equi-integrability on smaller $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a standard Borel space (i.e. $\Sigma$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a Polish topology on $X$) and $\mu$ be a (non-negative) *finite* atomless measure on $(X,\Sigma)$.

For any collection of sets $\mathcal{C}\subset \Sigma$, say that a family of functions $\mathcal F$ uniformly bounded in $L^1(\mu)$ is *$\mathcal{C}$-equi-integrable* if
$$\lim_{\substack{E\in\mathcal{C}\\ \mu E\to 0}} \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}} \int_E f d\mu=0.$$

**Question:** what are sufficient conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ that make a $\mathcal{C}$-equi-integrable family also $\Sigma$-equi-integrable?

In particular, is it enough that $\mathcal{C}$ be either:

0. any family generating $\Sigma$?
1. an algebra generating $\Sigma$?
2. the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu$-continuity sets in $\Sigma$?
3. a family of sets w.r.t. which $\mu$ is outer-regular? (or inner-regular, although I do not see why inner regularity should help)

**Bonus question:** what if we add assumptions on $\mathcal F$ instead?
For instance, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207982/on-equi-integrability-also-called-uniform-integrability) it is enough to have that $\mathcal{F}$ consists of $\mathcal{C}$-measurable functions. Is this also necessary?